# Best color to annotate against viridis

Tags: matplotlib

What would be the 'best' color to use for annotations against viridis. I am looking for a color with maximum clarity and contrast. Since there is so much science going into the viridis colorscheme, I am hoping there is an 'ideal' color for annotating on viridis. As you can see below, using a standard 'red' in matplotlib does not have nice visibility.

EDIT: I would not consider this pure opinion, as there is a rigorous science behind the viridis color scheme, and I am interested in answers that fit within that framework.

[image]

Comment: Well, it depends on many factors. Colors look different for different persons, on different monitors, different paper, different light conditions, ...  A "best" approach could use large enough characters with different edge and face colors.

Comment: The viridis colormap ranges from very dark to very light colors. So first one needs to note that there cannot be a single color which has good contrast to the complete map. Looking at the maximum distance in colorspace to any of the viridis colors, red would indeed be the best choice. In general, you can also consider using two different colors depending on the background, e.g. white for dark regions, black for yellow regions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the comment of @JohanC, I agree that using different face and edge colors is a good idea. Here is the example:

```py
# It is only a fraction of code to reproduce the figure, just an example of text highlight
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects
txt = axes.text(1.15, 8.25,"Good fit at dense and\nCO-rich conditions", color='w', rotation=45)
txt.set_path_effects([PathEffects.withStroke(linewidth=1, foreground='k')])
```

[image: patheffects on viridis]